# How to find the shortest route between two points based on cost surface?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grass-gis, cost-path

I have two locations: (A) starting point and (B) designation. Also I have a slope raster. I want to find the cheapest path between these two locations based on the slope (it is more expensive to travel over steep slope). What tools in which order do I have to use in order to get that (either ArcGIS or Grass GIS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several relevant commands in GRASS:

- [r.drain](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.drain.html) traces a flow through a least-cost path in an elevation
  model
- [r.cost](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.cost.html) determines the cumulative cost of moving to each
  cell on the input cost surface
- [r.walk](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.walk.html) outputs a raster map
  layer showing the lowest cumulative cost of moving between each cell
  and the user-specified starting points

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/783/looking-for-a-fast-open-source-raster-cost-distance-function-to-use-in-code/799#799) advices *r.cost*.
You can check [this](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/544) comparison between least-cost paths computed by *r.walk* and *r.cost* using a slope surface, and [this article](http://www.academia.edu/398732/Cost_Distance_Analysis_in_an_Alpine_Environment_Comparison_of_Different_Cost_Surface_Modules) page 4. And maybe [this thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Question-about-least-cost-path-td3902910.html) can be useful.